# Updating UI control after specific time elapsed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, controls

A WinForms application containing a custom control, `LabelProgressBar : ProgressBar`.

There is a method to make this control invisible (it works when called):

```
void statusIdle()
{
    labelProgressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

I need to make this control invisible (by calling the above method) a set amount of time after it has changed (calling other methods `statusCompleted` or `statusFailed`). For example:

```
void statusCompleted(string action)
{
    // this is working
    labelProgressBar1.Visible = true;
    labelProgressBar1.Value = 100;
    labelProgressBar1.setColourAndText(LabelProgressBarColours.WARNING_COLOUR, action + " Completed With Warnings");

    // this is not
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
    timer.Start();
}
```

The event handler for the timer:

```
private void timerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    statusIdle();
}
```

The control is not updating as required. What is the cause of this?

Comment: Make sure the ```Timer``` is also enabled when calling ```.Start()``` . ```StatusIdle()``` is called? Are you sure you do not get an Cross Thread Exception? When ```StatusIdle()```  is called from the ```Timer``` I am sure an invoke will be required.

Comment: @Tomek I just tried it, after adding `timer.Enabled=true`. Same issue. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: You will need to marshall this to the UI thread via an invoke , if its a threaded timer

Comment: ... or set the Form as the [Timer.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) or use a [System.Windows.Form.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), so no marshaling is required (as a plus, it'll also work :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for one-time operation you can use async handler method and add delay:

```
async void statusCompleted(string action)
{
    labelProgressBar1.Visible = true;
    labelProgressBar1.Value = 100;
    labelProgressBar1.setColourAndText(LabelProgressBarColours.WARNING_COLOUR, action + " Completed With Warnings");

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    statusIdle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timer is a local variable of a function. When the function ends, it ends too. So you probably need to move the declaration somewhere else.

Comment: No, that didn't help.

Comment: For a winform project, you can just add a timer into the form. and put your code in the timer_Tick event.